# Mysql where if condition

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, conditional-statements

Basically I have a table all customer will have a default row with `customer_group_id=0`

But some of this customer will belong to `customer_group_id=1`

When that happen a new row is created for customer with `customer_group_id=1` therefore now I have 2 rows for same customer but different customer_group_id.

Now when I fetch the data I need first to select * from customer table where customer_group_id =1 but if doesn't exist give me then with customer_group_id = 0  which is the default, and continue until it returns all data.

Anyone know the best way to achieve this fast?

UPDATE: screen shoot show 2 rows with same customer_id different `customer_group_id`:
[image]

I need to one or the other no both so hierarchy  is: if customer_group_id=1 exist then return that row and ignore the ohter otherwise return default which is customer_group_id=0

My full query:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `secondTable`.* FROM `customer` AS `main_table` 
LEFT JOIN `customer_group` AS `secondTable` ON main_table.customer_id = secondTable.customer_id 
WHERE (secondTable.customer_group_id = '1' ) 
AND (`secondTable`.`is_active` = '1')
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If you are trying to fetch all customers why not use just an select * from; and avoid duplicity using a "distinct" clause?

Comment: Sounds like schema needs normalization.. Although your question lacks details. Anyways, you can try the following: `SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE customer_id = $customer_id ORDER BY customer_group_id DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two groups, then aggregation is simple:

```
select customer_id, max(customer_group_id)
from t
group by customer_id;
```

In MySQL 8+, you can implement a more customer prioritization using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by customer_group_id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: First solution works fro me it only returns one or the other . I will give a try on second one but seems more time consuming to fetch data maybe.

Comment: One more thing what If have more groups like 2,3 and 4 but only be fetching for one of them or 0 the them otherwise 0 would that still work?

Comment: @JulianoVargas . . . If you only cared about two groups, you could add `where customer_group_id in (0, 4)` to either query.  This works because all customer have `0`.

Comment: The whole querry doesn't quite work for me as I need to do is select  everything  and LEFT JOIN to another table and Where second_table.customer_id=1  also if I  use in(0,2) or in(0,4)  it returns duplicates.

Comment: @JulianoVargas . . . The `group by` or `where seqnum = 1` removes the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is fetch all the rows for the customers with `customer_group_id=1` and then use `UNION ALL` to fetch the rows of the customers that do not have any row with `customer_group_id=1` by using NOT EXISTS:

```
select * from tablename
where customer_group_id=1
union all
select * from tablename t
where t.customer_group_id=0
and not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where customer_id = t.customer_id and customer_group_id=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the rows with `customer_group_id = 0` verify that there are no rows with `customer_group_id = 1` for the same `customer_id`. You can use a NOT EXISTS subquery:

```
SELECT c.*, g.*
FROM customer AS c
JOIN customer_group AS g ON c.customer_id = g.customer_id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM customer_group AS g2
    WHERE g2.customer_id = c.customer_id
      AND g2.customer_group_id = 1
      AND g.customer_group_id  = 0
)
```